# How to send push notifications from a dashboard to a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, dashboard

Currently working on a dashboard that controls and manages multiple processes going on in a flutter app (the link between them is firebase). Once I make a few adjustments on the dashboard, I want to be able to notify the user through a notification. Is this possible? Are there any useful resources for this?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is present in the official Firebase Cloud messaging documentation :

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/

Follow every steps carefully and you'll make it successfully work ;)